# Scala IDE Error -could not find/load main class

Tags: java, eclipse, scala

I am using Scala IDE 4.4.1.,using the jdk 8.When I try to run a scala program ,getting the error "Error: Could not find or load main class example.Credit" .

Comment: This [link](http://scala-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Error-Could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-test-spark-SparkTest-td4644206.html) might help you

Answer (score 3):

I was stuck with the same error a few days ago. In my case, it was an incompatibility of my JDK and the selected target JVM for my Scala project.

To check your current Java version, run `java -version` on the command line. To check your project JVM target in Eclipse, go to "Project > Properties > Scala Compiler" and check the target JVM (choose the same version as your current Java).

Hope it helps.

Comment: My java is `1.8.*` but I cannot find 1.8 in the Scala Compiler, what can I do?

Comment: Scala supports Java 8 since version 2.11.0. If you're using a previous version, you must downgrade your Java installation to 7.

Answer (score 1):

You should write object instead of class

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem so that is how I came to this link & would like to share my findings. In my case I found that incompatible jars where present due to it was throwing error. After providing correct jar issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I used Scala for Eclipse IDE,

The solution for this could be right click on project and select scala -> Set the Scala Installation, will set the scala path to this project and rebuild the same.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If the above mentioned solutions are already configured in your system and  still getting this error then consider reading my answer. When incompatible scala jars are referenced by projects, a red cross mark is shown at project level and no errors are shown in scala files. In this situation scala code doesnt compile and when executed shows the message "error could not find or load main class scala". Best solution is to go to the scala installation folder and to check if the jar is present there, if present then reference it else reference jar files that do not show error (red mark) at project level or at source code.